# Why does spring.profiles.active only read some profiles?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

Im making multiple profiles for my springboot app.

I have dev, local and test properties files.

[image: Properties files]

On application.properties file I only have this:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

If I change dev to local or test spring doesnt load the profile and the console stays like this:

[image: spring.profiles.active=test console]

Any reason why it doesnt work with local and test but it does with dev? I have exact same settings on all 3 and yet it doesnt work

Comment: Turn on debugging and logback, you might have errors during start-up

Comment: Using "mvn spring-boot:run -e -X" on the proyect doesn't print any error

Comment: Do you write log to a file? Maybe you created a `logback.xml` file

Comment: Yes I have a log file, but its empty. Not logback.xml

Comment: @LordHans please add those log files and configuration to your question. It would help everyone.

Comment: @ray log files are empty. Configuration is irrelevant, all 3 have the same. But only dev works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have multiple setting to set the profile? Perhaps although in you IDE Application Config?

Comment: I tried to run it with "mvn spring-boot:run" too where it should take the default properties and then use the profile that is set. But I had no luck with that

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how did you created the *local* and *test* `properties` files but from  your first screenshot they seem to be different from the others (see the different icons).

Check how did you create them.

Comment: I use Eclipse. It makes those icons different but they look the same from proyect folder. It worked before and it works in other proyect just not on that one